# Adding a sheet specifically to the left of another

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a daily progress report in an Excel sheet.

It has a button that adds a sheet to the right of the current sheet and names the new sheet day +1.

This is the code that starts the code that adds a sheet, and places it to the right of the previous sheet.

```
Dim cday As Integer
y = Sheets.Count
u = Sheets(y).Name
cday = Right(u, Len(u) - 3)
cday = cday + 1
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Select
ty = Sheets(y + 1).Name                     'Adds new sheet to the right of the current "day"

   Sheets(ty).Name = "Day" & cday           'renames sheet "Day +1"


   Sheets(y).Select
   Range("A1:AD148").Select                 'selects the area to copy on the active sheet
   Selection.Copy                           'copies the selected area
   Sheets(y + 1).Select                     'selects Renamed sheet
   ActiveSheet.Paste                        'pastes selection to new sheet
```

I am trying to place a "Report" sheet to the right of all the other sheets.

I hope that makes sense. I want it to be like this:

```
Setup,Day1,Day2,Report
```

**Question**

How do change the "add day" code to place a new sheet to the right of the previous day but to the left of the "Report" sheet?

Answer (score 0):

```
sheets.add(after:=sheets(sheets.count - 1))
```

but please stop selecting cells and don't use ActiveCell - it will catch you out and it's horribly inefficient

EDIT: my bad it should be

```
 sheets.add after:=sheets(sheets.count - 1)
```

EDIT2
This code definitely adds a page to the left of Reports and names it as +1 of the number of the page to the left

```
 Dim ty as long
 Dim cday As Long
 Dim y As long
 Dim u As String
 y = Sheets.Count - 1
 u = Sheets(y).Name
 cday = Right(u, Len(u) - 3)
 cday = cday + 1
 Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(y)
 ty = Sheets(y + 1).Name
 Sheets(ty).Name = "Day" & cday
```

But it does assume that Reports already exists, and is the last sheet in the workbook

Comment: could you please explain how I could get data from a set of cells without using selection or copy?  I could provide you the entire code if you wish

Comment: range("a2:c2").copy destination:= range("a3")    Will copy the range a2:c2 to the range a3:c3.    Sheets(1).range("a2:c2").copy destination:= sheets(2).range("a2")  will copy cells a2:c2 on sheet 1 into range a2:c2 in sheet3. No need to select or activate - just specify what you want excel to do.

Comment: so the code you gave me is not working for some reason.  I did edit my original post from before as I pasted it incorrectly.  I keep getting an error that says = was expected

Comment: So now my original code doesn't work because it keeps trying to name the "Reports" page not the "Day"

Dim cday As Integer
y = Sheets.Count - 1
u = Sheets(y).Name
cday = Left(u, Len(u) - 3)
cday = cday + 1
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1)
ActiveSheet.Select
ty = Sheets(y + 1).Name                     'Adds new sheet to the right of the current "day"

   Sheets(ty).Name = "Day" & cday           'renames sheet "Day +1"